# Popping, crackling noise from adapter with phone plugged in

Tags: adapter, sockets

I have a Samsung Galaxy 5 that I charge when at home with the Travel Adapter that came with it.  Today, when I picked the phone up (it was charging and turned off) to unplug it, I suddenly heard a pop! and then crackle! coming from the transformer-if I have that right-I mean the larger end of the adapter that plugs into the wall.

I unplugged it immidiately and the phone, adapter and socket do not show any problems to the naked, inexpert eye.

It's the first and only time anything like this has happened.  Usually the only two plugs I have in there are the adapters for my phone and laptop, sometimes but not always at once.

Before I plug it in again I'd hope to get a reading on whether this is a sign to replace the adapter, a fire hazard, or what.  Maybe I should start using one of those multi-socket bars?

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this can be caused by one of 2 things - either the wall socket or the wall plug.

Faults within the wall socket can give no visual indicators on the wall plug but if an electrician was to open it up it can, but not always, be immediately obvious.

Have you had the laptop charger wall plug in the same wall socket since this happened?  If you have and it was charging your laptop with pops or crackles then you need to call an electrician as there is a potential shock and/or fire hazard in the socket.

If it doesn't pop or crackle, particularly when charging the laptop, (you need to be sure to be drawing power from the wall socket) then it sounds like your phone charger wall plug is faulty.